# How can I achieve a "Karaoke Lyric" like effect with qt (QLabel)

Tags: qt, qlabel

[image]

So this is the effect what I want to get. Left and right parts of a label should have different filling/stroke colors (actually stroke size is also changed). And the proportion may change dynamically, and can be some position inside a letter.

I know I should override the paintEvent but still have no idea of how to do it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I actually don't know, but look at Qt Examples `Qml Video Shader Effect`

Comment: I would not start from a QLabel but rather from a QProgressBar, the initial text as a background image and while the time goes on you paint on top of it the other image with the highlighted text.